# Cannot install OpenCV on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: python, opencv, raspbian-buster

I've tried following this tutorial: https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/

I installed a fresh copy of Raspbian Buster on the Raspberry Pi 2 before following the tutorial.

It gave me errors after running “make -j$(nproc)”:

```
[ 34%] Building CXX object samples/opengl/CMakeFiles/example_opengl_opengl.dir/opengl.cpp.o
/home/pi/opencv/samples/opengl/opengl.cpp:14:14: fatal error: GL/glu.h: No such         
file or directory
 #include <GL/glu.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
 compilation terminated.
 make[2]: *** [samples/opengl/CMakeFiles/example_opengl_opengl.dir/build.make:63: 
 samples/opengl/CMakeFiles/example_opengl_opengl.dir/opengl.cpp.o] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:37187: 
 samples/opengl/CMakeFiles/example_opengl_opengl.dir/all] Error 2
 make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

At the very end of “make -j$(nproc)”:

```
[ 37%] Built target opencv_cvv
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

I am very new to raspberry pi's and OpenCV so I do not know if the tutorial is valid or outdated. Thanks for the help.

Comment: looks like a bunch of header files are missing

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes I see that, but I don't know why or how to install them

Comment: did you run all the commands in `Step 2: Install OS Libraries` - were there any errors? in second tutorial it's the apt get after *Then you can install all the important tools and libraries needed for OpenCV*

Comment: @JaromandaX As I mentioned before, the first tutorial had a "Timeout" error after executing "sudo apt-get -y install libgtk2.0-dev libtbb-dev qt5-default"

Comment: this timeout occur every time you tried? or did you try once and think it wasn't important to install those libraries?

Comment: @JaromandaX If I'm gonna be honest I was up at 3am so I don't remember too much, but I think I tried it twice.

Comment: well, that's why you have header files missing, as they did not install - I'd suggest trying from the beginning again, and if a step fails due to a timeout, try again until it works :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried following the tutorial and it failed, but this time with no timeouts. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: again, some headers missing which either suggests a) you haven't installed all the pre-requisites or b) the tutorials are inadequate and perhaps find another one :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I have already tried two tutorials, is there any that you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have special requirements to compile **OpenCV** from source it is not a good idea to do it, in particular by newbies. You find the OpenCV library in the default Raspbian repository. Just look at it with:

```
rpi ~$ apt list *opencv*
```

You will find 75 packages. Just pick that one you need and install it.

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

may be a good choice.

Comment: Thank you! This is so much easier than what I was doing, happy holidays!